# Beamer background color is not set when using XePersian

Tags: beamer, xetex, color, shading, xepersian

The background color is set when using `XePersian` and Beamer.

Minimal code:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=blue!50,top=blue!1]

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Arial}

\title{background}
\author{M.Ahmadi}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output with `TexLive 2020`:

[image]

Output without `XePersian`:
[image]

Comment: I can confirm your issue. However, are you sure this is a good idea to set such background color through your entire document ?

Comment: I will change the background color, I guess the problem is xdvipdfmx. Do you have a solution? Thanks

Comment: No, I do not have a solution.

Comment: You may open an issue [here](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues) if you want

Comment: Thanks, I reported in [here](https://github.com/persiantex/xepersian/issues/12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version  37.8 , [bidi](https://ctan.org/pkg/bidi) solved thanks to Mr. Vafa